# I passed a class to my front-end project through electron's preload, but I couldn't create an instance?

Tags: electron

the error displayed:

> Can't the class constructor ABC be called without "new"

frontend:

- "vite": "^2.1.2",
- "vite-plugin-html": "^2.1.0",
- "vite-plugin-vue2": "^1.4.2"
- vue2
- electron 14

I create a class and use preload like this:

```js
const { contextBridge } = require('electron')
class ABC {
    constructor() {
        this.item = {}
    }

    update() {
        console.log(`<<<<2021年09月16日 13:56:33>>>>`, this)
    }
}
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('$electron', {
    ABC
})
```

and I get ABC in my frontend:

```js
const {ABC } = window.$electron
const abc = new ABC()
```

But console throw an error that Class constructor ABC cannot be invoked without 'new'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expose complex types like Object via the `contextBridge`.

Only object properties that are considered 'simple' or a function are made available. The documentation states:

> The api provided to exposeInMainWorld must be a `Function`, `string`, `number`, `Array`, `boolean`, or an object whose keys are strings and values are a `Function`, `string`, `number`, `Array`, `boolean`.

The `contextBridge` will gut your class of methods and only retain properties. The documentation also states:

> Function values are proxied to the other context and all other values are **copied** and **frozen**. Any data / primitives sent in the API become immutable and updates on either side of the bridge do not result in an update on the other side.

This is another reason why classes will not work, they're typically passed by reference.

See the table of supported [parameters, errors and return types](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge#parameter--error--return-type-support).